# ActiveMQ 5.13.2 messages missing after restart

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am new to active MQ. Installed activemq 5.13.2. I am losing all my messages(including durable topic) after activeMQ server restart. Please find the below console screen shots before and after active MQ server restart.

[before activeMQ restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fslWc.png)

[After ActiveMQ restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KpDB.png)

This is my activemq.xml configuration:

```
<beans 
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">


    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery" 
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" 
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" persistent="true" useShutdownHook="false">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" > 

                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>



        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>


        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb" journalMaxFileLength="32mb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>




          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>


        <transportConnectors>

            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <destinations>
               <queue physicalName="testQueue">
               </queue>
               <topic physicalName="testTopic" />
         </destinations>

        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>


    </broker>


    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Are the messages marked as persistent? (see http://activemq.apache.org/why-do-i-not-receive-messages-on-my-durable-topic-subscription.html)

Comment: As @mjn states - messages are non-persistent by default if sent from the web console. For messages sent from an application, please double check your code

Comment: Are you sure that `${activemq.data}/kahadb` directory is not cleaned by whatever reason upon restart?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem seems to be the activemq console after a restart. The messages did not disappear, the console seems just to be showing something wrong.

[image: activemq console screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you need messages persisted across restarts the producer has to set them as persistent or the broker won't persist them. If you're routing using camel, the routes have to be marked as transacted or they will disappear too. So the broker can be told about durable consumers but the messages won't persist unless the producer (client) marks them as persistent before sending them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Queues persist Messages even after restarts.
2. Durable topics persist messages but the problem is console won't be showing those. Your durable subscribers will receive it once you restart the activemq.